# How to expand the height of the page in blueprint?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

Using blueprint.css, is there a way to stretch a `<div>` to the height of the page? I know how to do it in pure CSS, but nothing I've found suggests how to do it with blueprint, so I'm left with a `<div>` that has a background that stops halfway down the page (which looks terrible).

Comment: How did you end up doing the vertical stretch?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Blueprint class for this and a quick grep will show that the necessary CSS doesn't show up in the project.

Compass handles it with a set of [stretch mixins](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/layout/stretching/). `stretch-y` adds the following CSS to the element:

```
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
```

Since absolute positioned elements don't interact with floats, you'll need a `&nbsp;` in a `div` with the `background-color` that you want and the appropriate `width` (i.e. give it the right span-# class).

The purely presentational div feels like a hack, but I like it better than the [Faux Column](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) method.

You might want to to include:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and the following for your container, to give it 100% height and so the div's absolute positioning happens inside of it:

```
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
```

and maybe even this [IE hack](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html), though it might only be necessary with a footer:

```
<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```